# Liquibase package compilation when spec and body in same file

Tags: oracle11g, liquibase, continuous-deployment

I have a directory where the packages are kept in the below format ,both the package specification and body are kept in the same file ,the file name is abc.pkg

```
create or replace package abc
 IS 
  /* this package is utility to fetch employee related data*/


 END abc;
/
create or replace package body abc
 IS 

 END abc;
/
```

My changeset is

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
<changeSet author="curious" id="PKG_1" logicalFilePath= "package/abc.pkg" runOnChange="true">
    <sqlFile path="package/abc.pkg"
            relativeToChangelogFile="true"
            endDelimiter="/"
            splitStatements="true"
            encoding="utf8"
            />
</changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The build is successful but the package got error because of / , can anyone help me with this fix , as this must be the most common way of checkin the code into version control systems like GIT and SVN

Comment: Try `endDelimiter="\n/"` or `endDelimiter="\n/\n"`. But I usually split that up into two files and use `splitStatements="false"` and remove the `/` from the source file

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Thanks for the reply , but unfortunately both the endDelimiter is not working , I can see the body is visible in the spec and the error is `Spec 43 1 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" ` .Regarding splitting the spec and body , we have legacy code and it will be difficult to change the way people checkin the code now :(